# Does Jboss AS clustering support Spring-based web application Session replication automatically?

Tags: hibernate, spring, session, jboss, cluster-computing

The following are the related queries when JBoss has Spring Web application with back-end Hibernate and the load balancing is done by Apache Mod-jk.

1. Does JBoss AS clustering support Spring-based web application Session replication?
2. If it supports, would that be automatically done when we configure a JBoss cluster or should that be driven through explicitly setting up the JBoss cache?
3. Should the option of synchronous or Asynchronous replication be configured programmatic way or is there any way where it can be configured through clustering service XMLs where it would be applicable.
4. How do we deal the passivated Session and how does it behave in case of fail over?
5. Is there any specific links other than "JBoss High Availability Enterprise services with JBoss AS Clusters" are appreciated along with your experiences.